# Связь баз данных и вложенные классы

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-jpa

Не могу никак найти нормальный туториал как решить мою проблему
есть 3 модели

```
@Entity
public class User {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
    private String picture;
 
    private List<Chat> chatList;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Chat {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private Long count;
 
    private List<Message> messageList;
}
```

```
public class Message {
 
    private String name;
    private String picture;
    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
 
}
```

Хочу их связать для сохранения в бд, так как List это не примитивы сам в SpringBoot новичок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String picture;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user2chat",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id"))
    private List<Chat> chats;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Message> messages;
}

@Entity
public class Chat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long count;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="chat")
    private List<Message> messages;
}

@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String picture;
    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="chat_id", nullable=false)
    private Chat chat;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

}
```

Можете посмотреть [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) и [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)

Comment: А если брать что List<Message> не таблица, можно как-нибудь его преобразовывать?

Comment: @Svetl9chok, не понял Вашего вопроса. А как Вы собираетесь хранить сообщения?

Comment: Преобразовать класс Message пир сохранении в строку, а при считывании обратно

Comment: @Svetl9chok, лучше все таки хранить сообщения в отдельной таблице. Причин несколько: 1. сообщений в каждом чате может быть много; 2. нужно запоминать кто автор сообщения; 3. Нужно запоминать в каком чате оставляли сообщение; 4. нужно запоминать дополнительные данные, например, дата создания, дата модификации и т.д.

Comment: Ну а если вдруг все таки придется преобразовывать?

Comment: @Svetl9chok не придется, если вы так сделаете, то вы нарушите первую нормальную форму